# Scrollorama doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, superscrollorama

So I have a class assignment where I have to make a site for a Pokémon Go team (no, I kid you not). And I wanted to include some kind of cool scrolling animation, but something simple, like a fade in as you scrolled down this really simple one page site.

I tried about 4 different plugins, but since I know nothing about jQuery and Javascript except copying and pasting plugins, I'm quite bad at identifying what's wrong when there's an error (in this case, the plugin doesn't seem to be working at all). I don't know if it's because I didn't use classes or something, but since I don't have any CSS elements that are common between the divs I want to animate, I didn't think it was necessary.

This is the [plugin](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/), the [code](https://codeshare.io/huUkw) I have written and the [preview](http://amandasilvacarvalho.com/teammystic/) thus far. Any idea as to how to fix this? :o
And thanks for the consideration in advance!

Comment: You didn't follow the instructions correctly on initializing the plugin. Also, now would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Someone wrote this https://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qaD/